# How can I cheat an item into my inventory?

Tags: terraria, cheats

I want the Grand Design item so I can be a wire GOD! It takes too long to get the materials, and I want it now. Is there any way I can quickly cheat this item into my inventory?

Comment: Depending on your interpretation, this could be seen as multiplayer cheating, which we don't help with. But I don't think Terraria has PvP, so I don't think it'd be a problem.

Comment: It doesn't take that much to make a Grand Design. Save the Mechanic and the Goblin Tinkerer, buy the materials from the Mechanic, then combine them all at the Tinkerer's Workshop. It's (relatively) cheap and nearly effortless.

Comment: @Frank Terraria does actually have the option to engage in PvP.

Comment: @Frank As noted, Terraria does have PvP available, however, since it's mostly a single player or cooperative experience, and any cheat could be validly used for non-pvp content, I think we should go with the benefit of the doubt here.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to cheat an item into your game.

1. The easiest way is to use a character editor and add the item you want into your inventory. There's a bunch of them out there, just do a Google search. [This one](http://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/) is online so it doesn't have to be downloaded separately.
2. Download an "all-items" map, find the item you're looking for, then transfer it to your main world/character.
3. Start a local [TShock](https://tshock.co/xf/index.php) server on your machine, then join it as a client and use commands to spawn the item you want. The command you'll have to use is `/item [item] [quantity]`, where `[item]` is the name of the item (in quotes if the name contains spaces). If the quantity is not specified, it defaults to the max stack size for the given item.

Comment: Also world editor tools like TEdit allow to place any item any quality any quantity in a desired chest (at home, for example).